# Using CompositeType getting error from client for insert

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to have a column family that I can have a key for one CQL to get a row based on a key and another CQL to where I have a list of keys using the "IN" keyword and have an ORDER BY clause. The data I am getting is from the Column value not the Column Name. The issue I am having is trying to setup the column family to achieve this. I have this cli command to create the column family but when I go do an insert I get a odd exception about the Primary key. Below is the cli and the error when doing the insert of column values after the column family was created.

The cli command used to create the column family:

```
create column family video_item_details 
with key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(IntegerType,UTF8Type)'
and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and column_metadata = [
{column_name : key, validation_class: IntegerType, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name : name, validation_class : 'UTF8Type', index_type: KEYS}
{column_name : description, validation_class :'UTF8Type'}
{column_name : url, validation_class : 'UTF8Type'}
{column_name : play_time, validation_class : 'UTF8Type'}
{column_name : type, validation_class : 'UTF8Type'}
]
with caching='ALL';
```

the error during insert is:

Error while inserting com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part key2

The insert statement that was being attempted to be executed was:

```
INSERT INTO video.video_item_details(key, name, description, url, play_time, type) values
(1,'Gettysburg','Gettysburg Movie Trailer','test','2:53','Streaming')
```

Thanks for any advice on how to get Cassandra to do this type of query.

Best Regards,
-Tony

Answer (score 3):

The [DataStax Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) which you seem to be using supports *only* CQL3 and to me it looks like you have defined the table using the Thrift API. Combining the 2 will lead you into issues like this one.

I've posted a set of links on this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865703/difference-between-thrift-and-cql-3-columns-rows/17872321#17872321) that covers the differences between the 2 interfaces.

Comment: Thanks but I was told by the Cassandra team using CompositeType was the way to do this. When I used the CQL to create the column family I got error when doing the insert about unknown type which the Cassandra team said the creation of the column family using CQL will not preserve the order specified in the CQL statement which surprised me so I resorted to finer control. So with that in mind what is the proper way to get this done so inserts work as expected and also the ORDER BY?

Comment: Forgot to mention I am not using DataStax driver for creation of the table I am using cli. I am using CQL with the insert.

Comment: I am hoping that the capability of the cli or storage engine level commands is available at the CQL level since DBA's and Technical Leads like to fine level control over table creation. This is what I am really trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

That message means you're missing the "key2" column (the second part of your CompositeType).

But like Alex told you, the right way to do this is to create the table from CQL [i.e., with cqlsh] as well instead of trying to mangle CompositeTypes manually.  Anyone on "the Cassandra team" would tell you the same thing.  Source: I am Apache Cassandra project chair and DataStax Cassandra team lead.

Comment: Never mind I got it to work thanks for the help. There was no key2 in the example I posted so the error message was not useful.

Comment: Thanks I did finally get everything to work including the order by. In regards to CQL3 for table creation it does not appear to support all the cli examples have. There have been many cli examples for table creation that appear to indicate more control over table creation that CQL 3 examples appear to not have. I believe on stackoverflow there were even questions about cql versus cli.

Comment: CQL supports all cli definitions; just select or describe the table from cqlsh, to see how it makes sense of it.  As for which to use, that's very simple: cqlsh.  The cli is only still there for backwards compatibility.