# Cassandra column family displays differently through CLI and DataStax

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-cli

I'm trying to understand why I'm seeing different data in two ways to display Cassandra (1.2.x) column family columns.

In the first, I use `cassandra-cli` to `list` the rows in a column family.

```
[cassandra-cli]> list Users columns 1;
Using default limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: [rowkey1]
=> (name=[name1], value=[value1], timestamp=[timestamp1])
```

The data between `[]` is a placeholder for the value. In reality, they are displayed as the hex representation of a `byte[]`. The above seems to indicate there is one row with a single column (which has a name, a value, and a timestamp).

I'm doing what I think is equivalent with the DataStax v1 API

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder ()
    .AddContactPoint ("127.0.0.1")
    .Build ();

var metadata = cluster.Metadata;
var keyspace = "keyspaceName";
var tableMetadatas = metadata.GetTables(keyspace);

foreach (var tableMetadata in tableMetadatas) {
    var session = cluster.Connect(keyspace);    

    var rowSet = session.Execute("SELECT * FROM \""+ tableMetadata + "\" ", ConsistencyLevel.One);
    CqlColumn[] columns = rowSet.Columns;
                
    foreach(var column in columns) {
        Console.WriteLine("Column name: " + column.Name + ", type: " + column.Type + ", keyspace: " + column.Keyspace);
    }

    foreach (var row in rowSet.GetRows()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++) {
            String value = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(row.GetValue<byte[]>(i));
                        Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This displays

```
Column name: key, type: System.Byte[], keyspace: keyspaceName
Column name: column1, type: System.Byte[], keyspace: keyspaceName
Column name: value, type: System.Byte[], keyspace: keyspaceName
[The string value of rowkey1]
[The string value of name1]
[The string value of value1]
```

This seems to indicate there are 3 columns: one with name `key`, where the value is the `rowkey`; one with name `column1`, where the value is the value of `name1`; and one with name `value`, where the value is the value of `value1`.

How should I be interpreting these discrepancies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `cassandra-cli` you are seeing a "Thrift-perspective" of your storage, while using the DataStax driver and `cqlsh` will give you the "CQL-perspective".

There was a series of posts describing how these 2 are related. I've linked to these in my answer to the [Different between Thrift and CQL3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865703/difference-between-thrift-and-cql-3-columns-rows/17872321#17872321) question on SO.